# Mongodb running with node and PHP

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, xampp

I am new to Node.js and MongoDB. I have successfully got the mongoDB running with node.js and am able to start it up and store data inside of collections.  So the server is already running on localhost:27017 and works when accessing localhost:28017 .

Now that I have it running and working within Node, I wanted to test MongoDB out with PHP on my Xampp server running on Ubuntu, but am not able to get the phpinfo() to say it is using mongo yet.
I have followed the steps [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) to configure and install the driver. I have moved the mongo.so file to my xampps extensions and added the appropriate line in php.ini + restarted. But phpinfo() still doesn't show it.

I guess i am confused on the aspect of where do i put the mongo-php-driver folder? is this installed into the Xampp server as well, if so where do i put it?

It is already running and working using node.js , so was just getting confused why it wasn't working properly or getting connected.

Also while I'm at it, Is it possible to have php and node.js use the same mongoDB server running on port 27017?

EDIT:
I was able to get the server to at least give me an error message about the file after i edited the extension_dir to the correct path

```
extension_lib = "/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20090626"
```

i am now getting this error

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so'  - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

i guess I needed to change that php.ini option to get it to load properly.  but it seems I have compiled the wrong mongo.so build. I try again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
http://montenasoft.com/en/blog/how-install-pecl-php-extension-64bit-linux-while-you-are-using-32bit-xampp

Because xampp is compiled with 32 bit, but the mongo driver you compile is 64 bit.
You may have to compile your mongo driver with these:

```
phpize
CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Or just install apache2, mysql, php separately. I think this is a better option.